# Any other way to resolve V008. Unable to start the analysis on this file. [CLION]

Tags: c, pvs-studio, clion-plugins

Im trying to run basic C program with headers, unfortunately when I run *Check Project* or *Check  Current File*, i've encountered **V008** which is *Unable to start analysis on this file.* even though i've reinstalled all the applications, loaded the free license, and even the standalone version can't even run (still the same error)

here are the additional information:
Clion Version Build #CL-222.4167.35 (Build date is September 15, 2022)
PVS-Studio Vesion 7.20.63487

link to source file https://github.com/pawekz/PVSStudioSampleErrorCodeV008

I'm still learning though, hoping that you can assist me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the information. We have managed to reproduce the problem and we're working on fixing it.
For now, you can use this solution:

Try to add the path to the compiler binaries (*C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.2.3\bin\mingw\bin\*) to the PATH environment variable.